# BitTorrent is Protocol or application?

Tags: bittorrent

Apologies if i asked anything stupid.

I heard about Torrent/P2P sharing. I am still confused what is BitTorrent. I searched but didn't found anything to understand it. Somewhere i can see it is Protocol (uTP). Is BitTorrent Inc only company that provide torrent or is there similar other companies are exist with same service?

What are the difference between magnet link and tracker?

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is kind of all three. Bitorrent is a file transfer protocol, and utp was a lower level protocol that was developed by the writers of utorrent for more efficient transfers. They were bought over by Bittorrent Inc who maintain and the "Mainline" reference torrent client (aka the bittorrent client)  and the torrent specifications. They also use the protocol for things like bitorrent sync.

Torrents are decentralised by nature - no one 'provides' it. A torrent file or magnet link basically tells you "This file consists of these chunks. If you ask at tracker X Y and Z, it will point you at people who have these chunks". A magnet link is basically a link that provides this information without the need to download a file, but essentially there's no difference.

A tracker is a directory of 'peers' who are downloading a file, and seeds who have downloaded and are sharing the file. If you have no tracker, peers and seeds can communicate directly over DHT to find each other.

As for clients, there are many, and anyone can create a torrent, add it to a tracker and share a file. If Bittorrent Inc disappeared tomorrow, the torrents will still flow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What i understand is BitTorrent is a protocol used for P2P sharing. BitTorrent also provide client application to download the file. Torrent contain information of seeds. If we want to use BitTorrent protocol and want to use our client instead of BitTorrent then what steps are required.

Comment: @user2301394: You need to install and run your client.

Comment: Yup, and there's lots of clients for people with different needs, written by different people. BT Inc simply maintains the specification everyone uses, and have *one* client that supports the things any good client must, of many clients. Pick one, install it, try it with a linux installer download :)

Answer (score 0):

BitTorrent is a file distribution system used for transferring files across a network of people.

As you download a file, BitTorrent places what you download on upload for other users; when multiple people are downloading the same file at the same time they upload pieces of the file to each other.

BitTorrent pieces together the file you are downloading, to where the first part of a file you get may be the last part someone else gets.

As you continue to retrieve the file, BitTorrent also uploads data to other users. For example, a person with 98 percent of the file done is directed to the people with the 2 percent of the file they still need.